# INSERT a new column into an existing SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a "source data" table with columns A,B,C,D,E,F

I use this table to populate a live table by using

```
INSERT INTO LIVETABLE 
   SELECT * 
   FROM SOURCEDATATABLE
```

Recently, a new column (C1) was added to the `LIVETABLE`

All I want to do is insert a C1 column into my `SOURCEDATATABLE` between C and D so that it now is A,B,C,C1,D,E,F. There is no need to populate with data as the `LIVETABLE` accepts NULLs

Is there any easy solution?

EDIT - MISSING INFORMATION

This table is one of many and my approach to using the INSERT INTO is due to having to use dynamic SQL (for various other reasons) so I cannot specify the column names

Comment: You can only add columns at the end. You'll need to create a new table and populate it accordingly.

Comment: The easiest solution is to specify the fields in your insert query instead of selecting *.

Comment: As a best-practice, you should never `select *` in your code but name the fields you're selecting. That way you don't break anything in the case you're describing. If you don't want to change your code, just add the new field in the same position in both tables...

Comment: Thanks @Bartdude - I completely agree. I've edited my original question because I'm tied down by using Dynamic SQL - this table is one of many tables to populate

Comment: How does dynamic sql prevent you from specifying column names?

Comment: [Stop doing what you're doing](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx).

Comment: I've stopped!!!! 2 hours of refactoring code has, hopefully, bought me a lifetime supply of piece of mind!

Comment: Why the downvotes? Downvotes mena my question is badly worded or little/no research - not that you disagree with my approach to my solution/code

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason for the Mantra "I shall not use SELECT *" and you ran straight into it. Add the column to SOURCEDATATABLE (if necessary) and enumerate the columns in the SELECT clause using NULL for the new one.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to insert a new column between two columns is to create a new table with the columns in the order you want, copy the data into it, drop the old table and rename the new table with the old name. Make sure you remove primary key identities to maintain the identity column.